# Making bold in List of figures and List of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

For my List of figures and List of tables I need following behaviour:

[image]

and

[image]

In following code `#4` equals `1.1 Optimal solution of RNASP`.
When I change `#4` to `\textbf{#4}` all line becomes bold. But I need to make figure number bold, not the figure caption. Also I need a colon just after the figure or table number.

Current output is like this:

> Figure 1.1 Optimal solution of RNASP. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12

I need this:

> **Figure 1.1:** Optimal solution of RNASP. . . ... . . . . . . . . . . . 12

```
\def\@myfiguredottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
        \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \leavevmode
        \@tempdima #3 \relax
        \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
        {\ift@rkish{Şekil }\else{Figure }\fi\relax #4}\nobreak
        % input
        % \detokenize{#4}
        % result
        % \hyper@linkstart {link}{\Hy@tocdestname }{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Optimal solution of RNASP.\relax }}\hyper@-linkend
        % I need to get 1.1 from #4 and set it to a new variable
        % I need to remove 1.1 from #4
        \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
            \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
            mu$}\hfill
        \nobreak
        \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
        \par}%
}

\def\@mytabledottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
        \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \leavevmode
        \@tempdima #3\relax
        \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
        {\ift@rkish{Tablo }\else{Table }\fi\relax #4}\nobreak
        \leaders \hbox{$\m@th
            \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
            mu$}\hfill
        \nobreak
        \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
        \par}%
}
```

This is the definitions file (gsu12.def):

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\@normalsize}
\oddsidemargin 0.70cm 
\if@twoside
\evensidemargin 0.05cm
\else
\evensidemargin 1.95cm
\fi
\marginparwidth 1cm
\marginparsep 7pt
\topmargin -1.4cm
%\topmargin 0.5cm
%\topmargin 0cm
\headheight 12pt
\headsep 1.6cm
\footskip 5.6cm
\textwidth 15.5cm
\textheight 22.7cm
\columnsep 10pt
\columnseprule 0pt

%\footnotesep 7.7pt
%\skip\footins 10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt0
%\floatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
%\textfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
%\intextsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
% \@maxsep 20pt \@dblmaxsep 20pt
%\dblfloatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
%\dbltextfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
%\itemsep 2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt

%end of margins-etc
\lineskip 1pt \normallineskip 1pt
\ifd@uble \def\baselinestretch{2} \else 
\ifs@ngle \def\baselinestretch{1} \else \def\baselinestretch{1.5} \fi
\fi
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{13.6pt}\xiipt\@xiipt
\abovedisplayskip 11pt plus3pt minus6pt\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus3pt\belowdisplayshortskip 6.5pt plus3.5pt
minus3pt\let\@listi\@listI \let\currentsize=\@normalsize}
\def\small{\@setsize\small{12pt}\xpt\@xpt
\abovedisplayskip 10pt plus2pt minus5pt\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus3pt\belowdisplayshortskip 6pt plus3pt minus3pt
\def\@listi{\topsep 6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt\parsep 3pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
\itemsep \parsep} \let\currentsize=\small}
\def\footnotesize{\@setsize\footnotesize{11pt}\ixpt\@ixpt
\abovedisplayskip 8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus 1pt\belowdisplayshortskip 4pt plus 2pt minus
2pt
\def\@listi{\topsep 4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt\parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\itemsep \parsep} \let\currentsize=\footnotesize}
\def\scriptsize{\@setsize\scriptsize{9.5pt}\viiipt\@viiipt
 \let\currentsize=\scriptsize}
\def\tiny{\@setsize\tiny{7pt}\vipt\@vipt \let\currentsize=\tiny}
\def\large{\@setsize\large{14pt}\xiipt\@xiipt \let\currentsize=\large}
\def\Large{\@setsize\Large{18pt}\xivpt\@xivpt \let\currentsize=\Large}
\def\LARGE{\@setsize\LARGE{22pt}\xviipt\@xviipt \let\currentsize=\LARGE}
\def\huge{\@setsize\huge{25pt}\xxpt\@xxpt \let\currentsize=\huge}
\def\Huge{\@setsize\Huge{30pt}\xxvpt\@xxvpt \let\currentsize=\Huge}
\let\tmpnormalsize=\normalsize
\def\normalsize{\tmpnormalsize \let\currentsize=\normalsize}
\normalsize


\@fptop 0pt plus 1fil \@fpsep 8pt plus 2fil \@fpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\@dblfptop 0pt plus 1fil \@dblfpsep 8pt plus 2fil \@dblfpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\marginparpush 5pt 

\parskip 0pt plus 1pt \parindent 17pt \partopsep 3pt plus 1pt minus 2pt 
\@lowpenalty 51 \@medpenalty 151 \@highpenalty 301 
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty \@endparpenalty -\@lowpenalty \@itempenalty
-\@lowpenalty

\def\part{\cleardoublepage \thispagestyle{plain} \if@twocolumn \onecolumn
\@tempswatrue \else \@tempswafalse \fi \hbox{}\vfil \bgroup \centering
\secdef\@part\@spart} 

\def\@part[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \refstepcounter{part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart \hspace{1em}#1}\else
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}\fi \markboth{}{}
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \huge\bf Part \thepart \\vspace*{\fill}par \vskip 20pt \fi
\Huge \bf #1\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\par\egroup \vfil\newpage \if@twoside \hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage
 \fi \if@tempswa \twocolumn \fi}
\def\@spart#1{\Huge \bf #1\@endpart}

% making of the chapter
%\newcommand\@chapapp{CHAPTER}\vspace*{\fill}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{2.2cm}{\parskip \z@ \topsep \z@
%   \vspace*{0.2cm}{\parskip \z@ \topsep \z@
    \partopsep \z@ \parsep \z@ \itemsep \z@
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \begin{center}
        \vspace{2cm}
        \Large\bf \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \end{center}
        \par
        \vskip 1.5cm
    \fi
    \begin{center}
    \Large \bf #1
    \end{center}
    \par \nobreak \vskip 2.0cm}
}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\vspace*{0.6cm}
    {\parskip \z@ \topsep \z@
    \partopsep \z@ \parsep \z@ \itemsep \z@
    \begin{center}
    \Large{\bf #1}
    \end{center}\par
\nobreak \vskip 1.5cm}}

\def\chapter{
\vspace{2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\cleardoublepage\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\prechapter{
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\newpage\global\@topnum\z@
\@afterindentfalse \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \refstepcounter{chapter}
 \typeout{\vspace{2cm}\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
 \numberline{\thechapter}\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\uppercase{#1}}}\else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\fi
 \chaptermark{#1}
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{12pt}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{12pt}} \if@twocolumn
\@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]
 \else \@makechapterhead{#2}
 \@afterheading \fi}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]
 \else \@makeschapterhead{#1}
 \@afterheading\fi
}

\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus
 -.2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}{\large\bf}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus -1ex minus
 -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus
 -1ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection
 {paragraph}{4}{\z@}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection
 {subparagraph}{4}{\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus
 .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}

\def\chaptermark#1{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\def\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{leads}{\protect\numberline {}APPENDIX}
 \def\@chapapp{APPENDIX}
 \def\thechapter{\vspace{3cm} \bf\MakeUppercase \appendixname \vspace{3cm} \alph{chapter}}}


\leftmargini 2.5em
\leftmarginii 2.2em \leftmarginiii 1.87em \leftmarginiv 1.7em \leftmarginv 1em
\leftmarginvi 1em
\leftmargin\leftmargini
\labelsep .5em
\labelwidth\leftmargini\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
\def\@listI{\leftmargin\leftmargini \parsep 4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt\topsep
9pt plus 3pt minus 5pt\itemsep 4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\let\@listi\@listI
\@listi
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
 \labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
 \topsep 4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
 \parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
 \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
 \labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
 \topsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt 
 \parsep \z@ \partopsep 1pt plus 0pt minus 1pt
 \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
 \labelwidth\leftmarginiv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
 \labelwidth\leftmarginv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
 \labelwidth\leftmarginvi\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\def\@myfiguredottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
\interlinepenalty\@M
\leavevmode
\@tempdima #3\relax
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
{\ift@rkish{Åekil }\else{Figure }\fi\relax #4}\nobreak
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak
\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
\par}%
}

\def\@mytabledottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
\interlinepenalty\@M
\leavevmode
\@tempdima #3\relax
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
{\ift@rkish{Tablo }\else{Table }\fi\relax #4}\nobreak
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak
\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
\par}%
}

\def\@myalgodottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
\interlinepenalty\@M
\leavevmode
\@tempdima #3\relax
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
{\ift@rkish{Algoritma }\else{Algorithm }\fi\relax #4}\nobreak
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak
\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
\par}%
}
```

Besides I should mention that I don't use tocloft package. Because in its default behaviour it makes too many style changes that I should revert. Also algorithm2e package creates conflicts when I use tocloft.

This class file is also used:
https://files.fm/u/3nt5szx5

Comment: You are using some template. We do not know which one.

Comment: Thank you. I added a link to definitions file. https://files.fm/u/3c7ag2g2

Comment: Unless you redefine \l@figure and \l@table (which I did not find in your code), it will use \dottedtocline instead of \mydottedtocline.

Comment: \mydottedtocline is used. I suppose that directive exists in the cls file. I put here: https://files.fm/u/3nt5szx5

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434603/modifying-argument-in-macro